# How to verify a package was sent + delivered in iOS w/ SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app sort of like Yerdle (see yerdle.com for more) and I need some sort of SDK or something that will make sure a seller sends the item. There is no buying involved, so no transactions are necessary. I just need something that will make sure a user sends their package and make sure its delivered. I was thinking maybe scanning the package label so is there something for that?
So...
What can I use/do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about application/business model design, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

[AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/) has [methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2325/_index.html) to do code scanning.